How to workaround or fix Alpine.js on Webview on iOS?
Alpine.js functionality is not working when accessed with WebView on iOS (React Native). On Android it works as expected. Is there any way to setup WebView to make it work?
//App.tsx

import React from "react";
import { SafeAreaView } from "react-native";
import { WebView } from "react-native-webview";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <WebView
        source={{
          uri: "https://rwdevelopment.github.io/alpine_js_searchable_input/",
          //uri: "https://alpinejs.dev/component/dropdown",
        }}
        javaScriptEnabled={true}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

I tried to load multiple pages with Alpine.js in WebView and I was expecting working Apline.js. On Android in WebView it works just fine. On standard Safari on iOS it works just fine.
Thank you
